# The terminal says that computer_choice doesn’t exist even though it does

Tags: python

WHile I was attempting a simple rock, paper scissors, I ran into this proble. When I execute the file and input the user_input, it says to me that the variable computer_choice doesn’t exist, even though it does exist. I would appreciate if someone could help me, thank you.

```
import random

user_wins = 0
computer_wins = 0

options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

while True:
  user_input = input("Type Rock/Paper/Scissors or Q to quit. ").lower()
  if user_input == "q":
    break
  if user_input not in options:
    continue

    random_number = random.randint (0, 2)

    computer_choice = options[random_number]
    
    print ("The computer picked:", computer_choice + ".")

  if user_input == "rock" and computer_choice == "scissors" :
    print("You Won!")
    user_wins += 1
    continue

  elif user_input == "scissors" and computer_choice == "paper" :
    print("You Won!")
    user_wins += 1
    continue

  elif user_input == "paper" and computer_pick == "rock" :
    print("You Won!")
    user_wins += 1
    continue  

  else:
    print("You Lost!")
    computer_wins += 1
    continue
    
print("You won", user_wins,"times and the computer won", computer_wins, "times.")
print("Goodbye")
```

Comment: It looks like you've got an indentation problem. Where you have your first `continue`, the lines below that at the same indentation will never run. I assume the next three lines should be unindented.

Comment: Nothing in the `if user_input not in options:` block will be executed, because `continue` skips over it. I think you want to undent those lines. Use 4 spaces of indentation, then these problems will be more obvious.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i didn’t realise it at first because I was focusing on it being a software problem. I didn’t even think about indentation. Your comment was really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be careful with indentation when using python:

```
import random

user_wins = 0
computer_wins = 0

options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

while True:
    user_input = input("Type Rock/Paper/Scissors or Q to quit. ").lower()
    if user_input == "q":
        break
    if user_input not in options:
        continue
        # not at this level

    # at this level
    random_number = random.randint(0, 2)

    computer_choice = options[random_number]

    print("The computer picked:", computer_choice + ".")

    if user_input == "rock" and computer_choice == "scissors":
        print("You Won!")
        user_wins += 1
        continue

    elif user_input == "scissors" and computer_choice == "paper":
        print("You Won!")
        user_wins += 1
        continue

    elif user_input == "paper" and computer_choice == "rock": #not computer_pick
        print("You Won!")
        user_wins += 1
        continue
```

Also you wrote `computer_pick` in line 31, probably you mean `computer_choice`